# Roblox Studio how to rotate a shoulder properly

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I am trying to make my shoulders + arms + wrists look in the direction of my Third-Person camera direction

I allready scripted the head as i wanted and now i tried to copy and paste the code i had for the head to the shoulders but it doesn't work they just dont move

`
neck.C0 = CFrame.new(neck.C0.Position) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(y), 0, 0)

```
if isAiming and Rightshoulder then
    Rightshoulder.Transform = CFrame.new(Rightshoulder.Transform.Position) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(y), 0, 0)
    Leftshoulder.Transform = CFrame.new(Leftshoulder.Transform.Position) * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(y), 0, 0)
    print("hello")`
```

hello is getting printed and neck.C0 moves the head properly but my arms arent moving